# Avoid base 8 automatic conversion

Tags: python

I have a parameter which start with 0, something like `0100`. All I want is to *"stringify"* it and have

```
mystring = '0100'
```

with the leading `0` in the string, but Python is interpreting it automatically to base 8 and I get:

```
mystring = '64'
```

How can I avoid this and get exactly

```
mystring = '0100'
```

Comment: Can you show us an interpreter session? That's not what I'm getting.

Comment: Put `0100` in quotes like `'0100'` not alone.

Comment: Could you please post the code

Comment: the parameter do not come as a string that's the point

Comment: `oct(64) --> '0100'`

Comment: @FrançoisRichard: if it's a string, it should, that's the point.

Comment: I understand the conceptual point that my function should take the right input but it doesn't change that at some point is have to convert it to a string whatever it's inside or before the use of my function

Comment: You convert it *by typing it as a string* at the call site.

Comment: explain your situation. why do you *need* conversion at all?.... I know, because your input isn't a string. But *why*?

Comment: If you need leading zeros, then semantically, your input is not an integer. It is a sequence of digits. If you want to represent a sequence of digits or other characters in your program, the type to use is `str`, and you should write a string literal rather than an integer literal.

Comment: From where are you getting that parameter?

Comment: I suspect that somewhere, you've got the string `'0100'`, and you're trying to convert it to an integer either by calling `eval(s)`, `ast.literal_eval(s)`, or `int(s, base=0)`. If so, the solution is to not do whichever of those things you're doing, and instead do `int(s)` or `int(s, base=10)`.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: In Python 2.6+, you can use `0o100` instead of `0100` to avoid that confusion. Unfortunately, 2.6-2.7 will still give you `'0100'` from the `oct` function, but 3.x fixes that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please initialize your variable as a string `'0100'` if you require a preceding zero, not an octal number.

Comment: @user2357112 Well honestly, this is an assignment issue. At assignment, he should explicitly provide a string not an octal number if he needs a preceding zero.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: Honestly, that should be the answer... If you need to explain yourself, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
Myint = class int(mystr, base)
```

Use 10 for normal use.